# module not found when python script run from command line

Tags: python, module, package

Both `ISO8583.py` and `ISO8583Errors.py` are located inside the `ISO8583_payment` folder. Also, I created the dummy `__init.py__` inside `ISO8583_Payment` folder. When run ISO8583.py from the command line it throws me an error. But it works when I run from pyCharm IDE.

**ISO8583.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/ISO8583_Payment")
from ISO8583_Payment.ISOErrors import InvalidBitType,InvalidMTI,InvalidValueType,InvalidIso8583,ValueToLarge,BitInexistent,BitNotSet
''' I did not copy all the source code in here ''''

def ParseRawMessage(ISO8583TextFile):
    with open(ISO8583TextFile, 'rb') as in_file:
        contents = in_file.read()
        hex_bytes = binascii.hexlify(contents)
        IsoStr = hex_bytes.decode("ascii")
        Iso8583 = ISO8583()
        try:
            Iso8583.setIsoContent(IsoStr)
        except InvalidMTI as error:
            print("{0}".format(error))
        except InvalidBitType as error:
            print("{0}".format(error))
        except ValueToLarge as error:
            print("{0}".format(error))
        except InvalidValueType as error:
            print("{0}".format(error))
        except BitInexistent as error:
            print("{0}".format(error))
        except BitNotSet as error:
            print("{0}".format(error))
        except InvalidIso8583 as error:
            print("{0}".format(error))
        bitsAndValuesDictionary = Iso8583.getBitsAndValues()
        for v in bitsAndValuesDictionary:
            print('%s (BIT-%s) = %s' % (v['name'], v['bit'], v['value']))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ParseRawMessage(sys.argv[1])
```

**ISOErrors.py**

```
class ValueToLarge(Exception):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.str = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.str)

class BitInexistent(Exception):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.str = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.str)       


class InvalidValueType(Exception):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.str = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.str)       


class InvalidBitType(Exception):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.str = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.str)       


class InvalidIso8583(Exception):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.str = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.str)           


class InvalidMTI(Exception):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.str = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.str)       

#Exception that indicate that bit is not there.
class BitNotSet(Exception):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.str = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(
```

When I run from the command prompt, I have the following error.

```
C:\Projects\ATR220TA_Work_On_Progress\ISO8583_Payment>python C:\Projects\ATR220TA_Work_On_Progress\ISO8583_Payment
C:\Users\gobiraaj.anandavel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Projects\\ATR220TA_Work_On_Progress\\ISO8583_Payment'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
```

Is the file name `ISO8583Errors.py` or `ISOErrors.py`?

depending on this you have to use

```
from ISO8583_Payment.ISO8583Errors import ...
```

or

```
from ISO8583_Payment.ISOErrors import ...
```